# A question about Terence Tao's definition of limiting values of functions: am I grasping it correctly?

Tags: real-analysis, limits, metric-spaces, self-learning

In the book "Analysis I", Terence Tao provides the following definition:

> Let $X$ be a subset of $\textbf{R}$, let $f:X\to\textbf{R}$ be a function, let $E$ be a subset of $X$, $x_{0}$ be an adherent point of $E$, and let $L$ be a real number. We say that $f$ converges to $L$ at $x_{0}$ in $E$, and write $\lim_{x\to x_{0};x\in E}f(x) = L$, iff for every $\varepsilon > 0$, there corresponds a $\delta > 0$ such that for every $x\in E$ one has that
>   \begin{align*}
> |x - x_{0}| < \delta \Rightarrow |f(x) - L| < \varepsilon
> \end{align*}

Similarly, in the book ''Analysis II'' the same author provides the following definition:

> Let $(X,d_{X})$ and $(Y,d_{Y})$ be metric spaces, let $E$ be a subset of $X$, and let $f:X\to Y$ be a function. If $x_{0}\in X$ is an adherent point of $E$, and $L\in Y$, we say that $f(x)$ converges to $L$ in $Y$ as $x$ converges to $x_{0}$ in $E$, or write $\lim_{x\to x_{0};x\in E}f(x) = L$, if for every $\varepsilon > 0$ there exists $\delta > 0$ such that $d_{Y}(f(x),L) < \varepsilon$ for all $x\in E$ such that $d_{X}(x,x_{0}) < \delta$.

My question about these definitions is the following: what is the role of the set $E$?

As far as I have understood, the set $E$ tells us how we are approaching $x_{0}$.

Let us consider an example.

Let $X = \textbf{R}\backslash\{0\}\subseteq\textbf{R}$ and $f:X\to\textbf{R}$ be given by $f(x) = x/|x|$. Thus if we consider $E = (0,\infty)$, $x_{0} = 0\in\textbf{R}$ is an adherent point of $E$. Hence we have that
\begin{align*}
\lim_{x\to x_{0};x\in E}f(x) = \lim_{x\to 0;x\in(0,\infty)}\frac{x}{|x|} = \lim_{x\to 0;x\in(0,\infty)} 1 = 1
\end{align*}

Similarly, if we choose $E = (-\infty,0)$, $x_{0} = 0\in\textbf{R}$ is an adherent point of $E$. Thus it results that
\begin{align*}
\lim_{x\to x_{0};x\in E}f(x) = \lim_{x\to 0;x\in (-\infty,0)}\frac{x}{|x|} = \lim_{x\to 0;x\in(-\infty,0)} -1 = -1
\end{align*}

At last, if we choose $E = X$, the limit $\lim_{x\to 0;x\in E}f(x)$ is undefined.

But I am little bit unsure about this. From the context, I assume that we are immersed in the metric space $(\textbf{R},|\cdot|)\supseteq X\supseteq E$.

Here it is another example which may be enlightening.

Let $f:X\to\textbf{R}$, where $X = \textbf{R}\backslash\{1\}\subseteq\textbf{R}$, which is defined by
\begin{align*}
f(x) = \frac{x^{2} - 1}{|x-1|}
\end{align*}

If we choose $E = (1,+\infty)$, then $1$ is an adherent point of $E$. Thus we have that
\begin{align*}
\lim_{x\to 1;x\in E}f(x) = \lim_{x\to 1;x\in (1,+\infty)}\frac{x^{2}-1}{|x-1|} = \lim_{x\to 1;x\in (1,+\infty)}\frac{x^{2}-1}{x-1} = \lim_{x\to 1;x\in (1,+\infty)} x+1 = 2
\end{align*}

Similarly, if we choose $E = (-\infty,1)$, $1$ stills a adherent point of $E$. Thus we have

\begin{align*}
\lim_{x\to 1;x\in E}f(x) = \lim_{x\to 1;x\in (-\infty,1)}\frac{x^{2}-1}{|x-1|} = \lim_{x\to 1;x\in (-\infty,1)}-\frac{x^{2}-1}{x-1} = \lim_{x\to 1;x\in (-\infty,1)} -x-1 = -2
\end{align*}

Finally, if we choose $E = X = \textbf{R}\backslash\{1\}$, the limit $\lim_{x\to 1;x\in E}f(x)$ is not defined.

The same reasoning seems to apply to more general settings where we consider metric spaces other than the real line.

Am I interpreting it correctly? If not, how should I grasp this concept?

I am new to this. So any comment or contribution is appreciated.

**EDIT**

Here it is another example from the textbook which may help us understand it properly.

Consider $f:\textbf{R}\to\textbf{R}$ to be the function defined by setting $f(x) = 1$ when $x = 0$ and $f(x) = 0$ when $x\neq 0$. Thus if we choose $E = \textbf{R}\backslash\{0\}$ one has that $\lim_{x\to 0;x\in E}f(x) = 0$. On the other hand, if $E = \textbf{R}$, the limit $\lim_{x\to 0;x\in E}f(x)$ is not defined.

After this example, he provides the following argument:

> Some authors only define the limit $\lim_{x\to x_{0};x\in E}f(x)$ when $E$ does not contain $x_{0}$ (so that $x_{0}$ is now a limit point of $E$ rather than an adherent point), or would use $\lim_{x\to x_{0};x\in E}f(x)$ to denote what we would call $\lim_{x\in x_{0};x\in E\backslash\{x_{0}\}}f(x)$, but we have chosen a slightly more general notation, which allows the possibility that $E$ contains $x_{0}$.

Comment: Your example seems perfectly correct and clear. What do you mean by "ambient space"? The term "ambient space" has not been defined.

Comment: By ambient space I mean that: should we consider $0$ as an adherent point of $E$? If the metric space is $\textbf{R}$, it is ok to do so. But if the metric space is $\textbf{R}\backslash\{0\}$, then it doesn't make sense to consider $0$ as an adherent point. Maybe I am overcomplicating, but there is where my difficulty lies.

Comment: Hmm, now I see what you mean and I think this is a great question. I think I would amend definition 1 to say "$x_0 \in \mathbb R$ be an adherent point of $E$" to make it clear that in definition 1 $x_0$ is not required to be an element of $X$. If anyone disagrees with this interpretation, please chime in.

Comment: It's interesting that definition 2 only covers the case where $x_0 \in X$ (the domain of $f$), but I suppose that is all that Tao needs in order to achieve his goals in this book, and it might seem cumbersome to rephrase 2 to something like "Let $X$ be a subspace of a metric space $(Z, d_Z)$, let $(Y, d_Y)$ be a metric space, let $E$ be a subspace of $X$, and let $f:X \to Y$ be a function. If $x_0 \in Z$ is an adherent point of $E$, and $L \in Y$, we say that $f(x)$ converges to $L$ in $Y$ as $x$ converges to $x_0$ in $Z$ if for every ...."

Comment: One usually assumes that $x_0$ is a non-isolated point in $E$. You should check if Tao has this assumption somewhere. As for $X$, it plays almost no role, you can simply restrict the metric from $X$ to $E$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your understanding seems fine.  The usual definition of the limit has to do with the behavior of the function at points near $x_0$.  This more elaborate definition allows one to restrict one's attention to those points that are not only near $x_0$ but also in $E$, which is useful in some situations.  Sometimes people word this as "the limit of $f(x)$ as $x \to x_0$ through $E$", or "... along $E$".

You've already given one example: if $X$ is a subset of $\mathbb{R}$, and $E = (x_0, +\infty) \cap X$, then this definition recovers the usual notion of "limit from the right".

Another example that sometimes arises is when we have proved something about the behavior of $f$ on, say, a countable dense subset $E$ of $X$ (of which every point will be an adherent point).  We might not have enough knowledge about the overall behavior of $f$ to be able to say anything about the ordinary limit of $f(x)$ as $x \to x_0$, but we may be able to say something about the limit as $x \to x_0$ through $E$.

Comment: @EagerToLearn: A place where the notion arises naturally (i.e. more than as a convenient way to encompass unilateral limits when $X = {\mathbb R})$ is in complex analysis for [radial limits](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22radial+limits%22) (e.g. [Fatou's theorem](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22radial+limits%22+%22Fatou%27s+theorem%22)), [non-tangential limits](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22non-tangential+limits%22), [angular limits](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22angular+limits%22+%22complex%22) (e.g. [Julia theorem](https://encyclopediaofmath.org/wiki/Julia_theorem)), etc.

Comment: @DaveL.Renfro Thanks for the references! I did not have the opportunity to study these subjects yet. But I will take a look at it when I have the proper theoretical basis.

Comment: @EagerToLean: You may never study these specific topics unless you specialize in a certain area of math, but you don't have to "study these subjects" to have an idea of what these kinds of limits are (but maybe you're not ready yet to see this).